# Find all vectors tangent to the set $A$ in the point $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, tangent-line

> Let: $$\displaystyle{ A = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x\left( x^2-4y^2 \right)\left( x-y^3 \right) = 0 \right\}}$$Find all vectors tangent  to the set $A$ in the point $(0,0)$

I know that vector $v$ is tangent to the set $A$ in the point $a$ when exist $x_n \in A\backslash \left\{a\right\}$ such that $x_n \to a$ and $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{x_n-a}{||x_n-a||}=\frac{v}{||v||}$. 
However I don't know how to use this knowledge in this task because so far in the tasks I determined $y$ depending on $x$, but in this task it is too difficult and there is definitely a better way.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$A=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 \;\; x=0 \vee y=\frac x2 \vee y=-\frac x2 \vee y=x^\frac 13\}$$

thus there are three tangents.

$$x=0$$

$$y=\frac 12 x$$
$$y=-\frac 12 x$$

Comment: Firstly I have a question: why there is no tangent in $y=x^\frac 13$? Secendly I don't know if I do this well: for example for $y=\frac 12\ x$: $x_n=(\frac 1k\, \frac{1}{2k^2}) \in A, x_n \to a=(0,0), x_n-a=(\frac 1k\, \frac{1}{2k^2}), ||x_n-a||=\sqrt{\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{4k^4}}=\frac{1}{k}+o(\frac{1}{k}), \frac{x_n-a}{||x_n-a||}=(1,1)$

Comment: But I am very uncertain about my reasoning ...